# How is git supposed to resolve URLs generated by gitlab?

Tags: remote, repository, gitlab

Having gitlab successfully installed and running, I tried to import an existing project. To do so I created an empty project and then got a list of instructions on the projects page, how to push my existing repo data into the gitlab project:

```
    cd existing_git_repo
    git remote add origin gitlab@gitlab.mydomain:root/testproject.git
    git push -u origin master
```

But when doing so, I get the following message:

```
    fatal: 'root/testproject.git' does not appear to be a git repository
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

When looking into my repositories folder, the repository has been created there by gitlab and when using the http-URL instead of the git-URL everything is working as expected.

How is **git push** supposed to know how to resolve from **"gitlab@gitlab.mydomain:root/testproject.git"** to **"gitlab@gitlab.mydomain:/home/gitlab/repositories/root/testproject.git"**? Is gitlab supposed to create the git server? If so, where should I start digging to find out why no repository is found where gitlab told me to point my remote at?

-

**Edit:** when greping for "root/testproject.git" I get the following results:

```
    [gitlab@gitlab gitlab]# grep -r "root/testproject.git" *
    gitlab/log/sidekiq.log:Initialized empty Git repository in /home/gitlab/repositories/root/testproject.git/
    gitlab-shell/gitlab-shell.log:I, [2014-01-23T16:38:16.974051 #5390]  INFO -- : Adding project root/cashio.git at </home/gitlab/repositories/root/testproject.git>.
```

**Edit2:** If that helps: using **git remote set-url gitlab gitlab@gitlab.mydomain:/home/gitlab/repositories/root/testproject.git** instead works as expected.

Comment: Did gitlab tell you to add this remote "gitlab@gitlab.mydomain:root/testproject.git" ?

Comment: Yes, I C&P'd the message you read there and just removed the actual domain.

Comment: I don't know anything about gitlab, but I suggest that you review your gitlab configurations.  Is there some kind of path variable that you need to fix so that gitlab provides the path correctly?

Comment: @Zoredache I didn't just check my configuration manually, I also ran all the check-scripts that were mentioned in the docu. The reason for it to no work was lack of knowledge on my end (and maybe lack of proper documentation). I ignored that you had to use keys and weren't allowed to do password authentication with the default setup of gitlab-shell (maybe it's possible to configure password authentication as well, but so far I wouldn't know how to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the reason was pretty simple but not obvious to me. Everything is described here: https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/issues/3686

It boils down to: one has to use keys with gitlab-shell and have gitlab manage these keys which I didn't know. When using key-authentication and having the keys stored using the gitlab-webinterface, pushing, pulling and cloning now works as expected.

Comment: As I mentioned, I am not familiar with gitlab, but if using keys makes it work, then I assume the keys get a force-command added to the key or something.  If that is the case, you might be able to make that work for password auth by configuring a ForceCommand for a user in your sshd_config.  You really should use key-based auth though.

Comment: @Zoredache Thanks for the hint. The keys get indeed added a force command. I know why one should use keys instead of passwords and intend to use them when running the project. Your hint made me understand how gitlab and gitlab-shell interact a lot better. Thanks a lot for your time.